# iOS - Core Data - Creating an empty NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

My `Core Data` stack is as follows:

- **Private Queue Managed Object Context (Parent)**
- **Main Queue Managed Object Context (Child)**

My issue is that I want to create a **Search** functionality using ONLY data downloaded from the server. 
The ideal solution was to create a new-empty `NSManagedObjectContext`(to be used a temp write/read context) without the need to have a `Persistent Store` or a `Parent` but Xcode will crash.

Any alternatives?

PS: One other solution would be to have a `tempAttribute` flag (bool attribute) that would be set to `true` only in the current context (which has a parent the **Private Queue Managed Object Context** but I want to avoid it.

Comment: Just to be clear … the problem is that **Xcode is crashing**.  There should be a workaround for that.  You should not use a non-ideal design because Xcode is crashing.  Maybe if you describe how Xcode is crashing, someone can help with that.

Comment: Xcode is crashing because it doesn't support an NSManagedObjectContex without a parent (Persistent Store or Parent NSManagedObjectContex). Quote: `without the need to have a Persistent Store or a Parent`

Comment: When Xcode crashes, you see (eventually) an alert window which says "The application Xcode has unexpectedly quit."  And you must relaunch Xcode in order to continue working.  I think what you are trying to say is that *your app* is crashing.  Big difference :)  When *your app* crashes while being debugged in Xcode, the "Run" (right-pointing triangle) button on the left side of the toolbar becomes enabled again, and a message may be logged to Xcode's console in the debug area.  I'm going to give an answer assuming that it is *your app* and not Xcode which is crashing.  Tell me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your managed object context does need a NSPersistentStore, but there is one [type of NSPersistentStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/persistent_store_types?language=objc), NSInMemoryStoreType, which in fact does not persist data to the disk.  I think that is what you are looking for.  Here is some Swift code for creating a managed object context with such an *in-memory* persistent store:

```
// Create Core Data Stack
guard let dataModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main]) else {return}
let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: dataModel)
do {
   try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType,
                   configurationName: nil,
                                  at: nil,
                             options: nil);
} catch {
    print("Error creating store: \(error)")
}
let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
```

A good follow-up question is: *Why does Apple call it NS**Persistent**Store if not all of its types are persistent?*  Well, maybe they added the *in-memory* store store type at the last minute before macOS 10.4 was frozen for release and did not have time to change the name :)

You should also read through the [differences among store types](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH23-SW1)